# Maven repository for QuickFIX/J library

Tags: maven, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am using QuickFIX/J in the newest version (1.6.0) and want you to ask if you know any Maven repositories to integrate in my pom file?
I could manually add the jar files to my local repository but maybe there is a nicer and quicker way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QuickFIX/J version 1.6 and newer can now be found in Marketcetera repository.

Add repository to your Maven pom file:

```xml
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>marketcetera</id>
         <url>http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven</url>
      <snapshots>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then the artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>quickfixj</groupId>
   <artifactId>quickfixj-all</artifactId>
   <version>${quickfix.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

`${quickfix.version}` can be **1.6.0**, **1.6.1**, or **1.7.0-SNAPSHOT**, but also older version are available there. They host both floating point-based and BigDecimal-based versions. The default is **floating point**. To use BigDecimal versions, append `'-bd'` to the version.

---

**EDIT** (13th August '15):

Unfortunately this QuickFIX/J bundle does **NOT** contain dependent **[Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org)** library for network transportation, you have to add also this to your Maven pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.mina.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

where `${apache.mina.version}` is actual version of library (these days it's **2.0.9**).

Without that you will be getting `NoClassDefFound` exceptions.

---

**UPDATE** (22.7.2016):

Good news!

Since the release of new QuickFIX/J version **1.6.2** the library is now available from official **Maven repository** so the only thing you need is following artifact in your pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
   <artifactId>quickfixj-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

More info at [official pages](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quickfixj/quickfixj-core/1.6.2).

Comment: Thank you, for this answer. It saved me from my struggle to get it compiled in Maven.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Marketcetera repository.  Add this to the list of repositories in your POM:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MarketceteraRepo</id>
        <url>http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

By the way, you could have looked up this information from the [QuickFIX/J User Manual](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.3/installation.html).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response.. I saw this one at the user manual too. But this repository has only the quickfix-jars of version 1.3.1 and not of the actual, the 1.6.0. Or am I wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are correct.  This repository only seems to have version 1.3.1 and not 1.6.0 (assuming the latter is a valid version).

Answer (score 1):

Marketcetera switched to using org.quickfix for the group ID, so the proper Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
    <artifactId>quickfixj-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2-bd-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```